# Azure Functions v2: logging customization in host.json

Tags: logging, .net-core, azure-functions

I would like to adjust the logging behavior of an Azure Functions app (v2, .NET Core). Therefore I adjusted the host.json as follows:

```
"logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
        "default": "None",
        "Host.Results": "Information",
        "Function": "Information",
        "Host.Aggregator": "Information"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
            "isEnabled": false,
            "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 5
        }
    }
}
```

Two questions in that context:

Since I did that I see no new logs in Application Insights. Why?

Furthermore what does fileLoggingMode and its possible values never, always and debugOnly stand for? I haven't found a good explanation for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see no new logs in Application Insights. Why?

Since your log level is set to Information, are you doing `Log.LogInformation()`  from your code ? If you are using `Log.LogDebug()` try changing it. More information about Log Filtering -> [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#log-filtering)

> what does fileLoggingMode and its possible values never, always and debugOnly stand for?

By default the `fileLoggingMode` is set to `debugOnly`. Which means its helpful only when the function is published in Azure. If you want to see diagnostic logs for your function when running locally, you need to set it to `always`

Comment: In this context it is also good to check the daily cap in Application Insights (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing#review-usage-and-estimate-costs) and how verbose the logging is of other Azure Functions using the same Application Insights instance.